# I want to make a new dataframe with a result of randomforest predict_proba

Tags: numpy, dataframe, random-forest

I made a randomforest classifier which has 8 classes.

```
rf_clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

this code's result looks like

```
array([[0.145 , 0.025 , 0.02  , 0.01  , 0.0025, 0.07  , 0.715 , 0.0125],
   [0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 1.    , 0.    , 0.    ],
   [0.0925, 0.3375, 0.175 , 0.01  , 0.0625, 0.1375, 0.0875, 0.0975],
   [0.0525, 0.72  , 0.065 , 0.005 , 0.0025, 0.1125, 0.025 , 0.0175],
   [0.    , 0.    , 1.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ],
   [0.6675, 0.0425, 0.0025, 0.0075, 0.005 , 0.0225, 0.235 , 0.0175]])
```

I want to make a new dataframe named 'probability' whose columns names are '1','2' ...'8'.
How can I do this?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(rf_clf.predict_proba(X_test))`?

Comment: it was so simple and easy.. lol Thank you!